# Two dices are rolled 10 times. What is the probability of (1,1) to appear exactly once?

Tags: probability

Two dices are rolled exactly 10 times. What is the probability for (1,1) to show up :
a) Exactly one time?
b) At least one time? (Two ways of solving b would be helpful)

What I thought would be for:

a)

This is a binomial distribution, therefore, for the (1,1) case to appear exactly once.
It should be:

$(\frac{35}{36})^9  * \frac{1}{36} * {10\choose 1} = \frac{35^9}{36^{10}}*10$ ?

b)

First solution would be calculating the cases when there is no (1,1):

$1 - (\frac{35}{36})^{10}* {10 \choose 1}$.

The second solution would be by calculating all the correct cases (we will use the first point a)):

$\frac{35^9}{36^{10}}* {10 \choose 1} + \frac{35^8}{36^{10}} * {10 \choose 2} + ... + \frac{35^0}{36^{10}}* {10 \choose 10}$

Comment: b)1) should be $1 - \left(\frac{35}{36}\right)^{10}$ because you count $10$ independent dice throws with probability $\frac{35}{36}$ each

Comment: I wasn't sure about that. Could you give an explanation?

Comment: Yes, now makes sense ! Thanks

Comment: For (a), $\ X\sim B(10, \frac{1}{36})$. So, $\ P(X=1) = {10\choose 1} \times  (\frac{1}{36})^1 \times  (\frac{35}{36})^9$. So yes, your answer for (a)  is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of getting any pair of dice values is $\frac{1}{36}$

The probability of rolling snake eyes exactly once in ten rolls is the probability of rolling 9 non-snake eyes and one snake eyes. There are ten orders this can occur in.

$(\frac{1}{36}(1 - \frac{1}{36})^{9}) * {10\choose1} $ ~ .20958

The probability of rolling atleast one snake eyes in ten rolls is one minus the probability of not rolling any snake eyes in ten rolls.

$(1-(1 - \frac{1}{36})^{10})$ ~ .2455